# Как правильно выполнить thread

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Разбираюсь как работать с потоками в Swift, нашел пример выглядит вот так

```
private func searchForTweets() {
    if let request = twitterRequest {
        request.fetchTweets { [weak self] newTweets in
            if let wSelf = self {


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if !newTweets.isEmpty {
                        tweets.insert(newTweets, at: 0)
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но в `swift 3`, `Dispatch` был изменен и я не могу найти нормального туториала (посоветуйте если вдруг есть под рукой. В офф доках тоже не нашел)

Так вот так как я понял я сделал вот так

```
private func searchForTweets() {
    if let request = twitterRequest {

        request.fetchTweets { [weak self] newTweets in
            if let wSelf = self {
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                            if !newTweets.isEmpty {
                                wSelf.tweets.insert(newTweets, at: 0)
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
```

Но я не уверен, что это правильно. Меня смущает то, что в примере передают как параметр `dispatch_get_main_queue()` , а я у себя ничего такого не передаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Теперь записывается

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     <#code#>
}
```

Эти вопросы хорошо освещали накануне выхода Swift 3. [Вот статейка](https://swiftable.io/2016/06/dispatch-queues-swift-3/), к примеру.

Как по мне, в Swift 3 очень интуитивно сделали для записи. Отвечаем на 3 вопроса и записываем в код:

```
Что?          Где? Как?
DispatchQueue.main.async
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter
DispatchQueue.global().async и т.д.
```

---

Немного о потоках:

`Main queue`- главный поток. Основная его задача это выполнение кода, отображающего пользовательский интерфейс. Из записи `DispatchQueue.main` видно, что это `singleton`, т.е. этот поток один.

Никогда не выполняйте "тяжелые" задачи в главном потоке, т.к. это приведет к подтормаживаниям/фризам.

Ни в коем случае вызывайте метод `sync` на `Main queue`, потому что это приведет к `deadlock` приложения.

`Global queue` - глобальные очереди. Для выполнения любы задач, которые не должны относиться к главному потоку. К примеру, сетевые запросы, вычисление числа Пи и др.

Пример использования:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    //Получаем данные с сервера
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //Отображаем полученные данные
    } 
}
```